# write a MIDI file in C++

Tags: c++, midi

Hi I Have some problems finding the right information about this and would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.
How do you code a midifile? e.g. how can I write a snippet that plays a random tone for 1 second.
Basically what I would need to get done is representing differnet midi melodys as vectors of some sort? How can I do this..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also read up on the MIDI file spec (quick search turned up [this](http://253.ccarh.org/handout/smf/)) and generate the file yourself.  Using a library is probably easier, but the MIDI file format isn't too complicated, especially if you already know how MIDI works (eg. note on/note off messages).

Comment: Hi thanks for the Link, it seems useful. I would absolutely want to generate the file myself, just a simple one or two tone file to get the Idea..