# What is the structure of a MIDI file?

Tags: language-agnostic, midi

I want to manually have a function that creates a MIDI file according to users demands, for example.

User write 2 patches that contain 8 bars of 4 quarters of A4 (Concert A - 440hz) and C4 (each as a seperated channel) on 120 speed, at velocity 100, instrument piano (01) and patch 49 or whatever.

How should the MIDI file look like according to the above.
My goal is to learn how to create a function that generates MIDI data, then write everything to a MIDI file.

So first I have to understand how to create this function or to understand 'MIDI-file language' so I can write it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=midi+file+structure start with that please. also there are a lot of libs that implement midi.

Comment: The problem is I am looking to create my own lib and I don't understand the MIDI file script, believe me I tried that link you provided.

Comment: Actually, if you have a good MIDI file generator API, that would be good. Not a player, but a command generator according to organized Enums/Structures or other .NET symbols for patch, note and all the other MIDI stuff, so I don't have to talk binaric.

Comment: Heh, Google search. First result: This page.

Comment: So it's good or not? :)

Comment: @Matthew You won me to that comment ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From all the MIDI info I read recently, [this](http://www.recordingblogs.com/sa/tabid/88/Default.aspx?topic=Musical+Instrument+Digital+Interface+(MIDI)) seems to be the most comprehensive tutorial, in the other hand the following link is a good place to get started:

[MIDI structure at the official MIDI website](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php)

Also, [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) is a .NET library that works with MIDI files by Mark Heath.
I've also found this link very useful, I thought why not share it with people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956608/write-a-midi-file-in-c).

I think this is the best .NET API for messing with MIDI files.

Comment: Your second link (http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) is broken.

Answer (score 16):

Other good links on the MIDI file format can be found here:

- [(.mid) Standard MIDI File Format](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm)
- [The MIDI Technical Fanatic's Brainwashing Center](http://midi.teragonaudio.com) (really nice resource)
- [Essentials of the MIDI protocol](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/articles/linuxmidi/misc/essenmidi.html)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks, fixed with a link to a mirror (which I maintain)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that [Somascape](http://www.somascape.org/midi/tech/mfile.html) has a very comprehensive and well-laid out resource for MIDI file structure and MIDI protocol. (Check out the drop-down menu on their site for additional resource pages). It helped me a lot recently while writing a MIDI framework for Swift.