# What kind of Encoding does a standard midi file use?

Tags: python, file, encoding, midi

Here's what brought this question up:

```
with open(path + "/OneChance1.mid") as f:
  for line in f.readline():
        print(line)
```

Here I am simply trying to read a midi file to scour its contents. I then receive this error message:  `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 153: character maps to <undefined>`

If I use `open()`'s second param like so: with `open(path + "/OneChance1.mid"m encoding='utf-8) as f:` then I receive this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 13: invalid start byte`

If I change the encoding param to ascii I get another error about an ordinal being out of range. Lastly I tried utf-16 and it said that the file didn't start with BOM (which made me smile for some reason). Also, if I ignore the errors I get characters that resemble nothing of the kind of data I am expecting. My expectations are based on this source: http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html

Anyway, does anyone know what kind of encoding a midi file uses? My research is coming up short in that regard so I thought it would be worth asking on SO. Or maybe someone can point out some other possibilities or blunders?

Comment: Things like UTF-8, UTF-16 and ASCII are *text* encodings. [MIDI](http://www.midi.org/aboutmidi/tut_midifiles.php) is not a text format.

Comment: Ideas abot the dead link (`www.sonicspot.com` not found)? BTW: the encoding of text in meta events may be worth a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MIDI files are **binary content**. By opening the file as a text file however, Python applies the default system encoding in trying to decode the text as Unicode.

Open the file in *binary mode* instead:

```
with open(midifile, 'rb') as mfile:
    leader = mfile.read(4)
    if leader != b'MThd':
        raise ValueError('Not a MIDI file!')
```

You'd have to study the [MIDI standard file format](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm) if you wanted to learn more from the file. Also see [What is the structure of a MIDI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087277/what-is-the-structure-of-a-midi-file)

Answer (score 3):

It's a binary file, it's not text using a text encoding like you seem to expect.

To open a file in binary mode in Python, pass a string containing `"b"` as the second argument to [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

[This page](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) contains a description of the format.

Comment: That makes sense. You wouldn't know how to specify this when reading a file in python would you? If I leave out that parameter it defaults to 'charmap'. 'binary' and 'none' also do nothing.